# working with active and hover links in css?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, html-lists

I have this `li` list, but I want to know how to have the current page link have a background of white (`li:active`)

CSS:

```
#layout-three-liquid2 #section-navigation ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#layout-three-liquid2 #section-navigation ul li
{
    margin: 0 0 0em;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#layout-three-liquid2 #section-navigation ul li:hover{

    background-color:white;



}
#layout-three-liquid2 #section-navigation ul li a:active{

    background-color:white;



}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
   <li><a active="current" href="#page1">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#page3">Replies</a></li>
</ul>
```

But its not working, how can I solve this?

Comment: Are you 100% sure you're within `#layout-three-liquid2 #section-navigation`? Please show the full HTML

Comment: `:active` means "Being activated (e.g. by being clicked on)", not "Having an href attribute that resolves to the URI of the current page". It is nothing to do with the non-existent `active` attribute.

Comment: edited the css code, to show you the whole scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code `li:active` isn't valid/correct. You need to specify a class and the link in your CSS like this:

```
#section-navigation ul li a.current {
  background-color:white;
}
```

Comment: this deos not work, updated css code, to show you the whole ul css class

Comment: @sarfaz this works thanks, but it highlights only the link, i need to highlight the whole li! it looks so ugly lol :)) +1 upvote from me

Comment: @getaway: Good news. For li you need to use the same class at li not link and use li.current in css instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do `<a active="current">`

because `active` isn't a valid attribute of the `<a>` element.

try using `class=current` instead.

then in your css you can target the element with

```
#layout-three-liquid2 #section-navigation ul li a.current {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're abusing CSS pseudo-classes. `:active` and `:hover` are special values, those are used when the link is clicked (has the focus) and when the user moves the mouse pointer above it.

CSS classes should be used instead:
CSS:

```
#layout-three-liquid2 #section-navigation ul li a.current{

    background-color:white;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
   <li><a class="current" href="#page1">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#page3">Replies</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that :active doesnt mean the page you are currently on, it just means that the link is being clicked. (It might works in framesets also)

You have to do some server side scripting to set the class to link_active or something like that.